# SwiftUI List/Destination Navigation Bar Title Ghosting

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm experiencing a strange visual bug with navigation bar titles. This swiftUI app has
a basic master/detail type view with a List view and a Detail view that is presented
with a NavigationLink. That Detail view is then a list of Texts displaying information
or a list of TextFields when the page is in the edit mode.

When in the Detail view with edit mode and I scroll to the bottom item in the list and
edit it then the navigationBarTitle on the first view has a ghost of the "Detail"
navigationBarTitle of the second view. If I don't scroll the ghosting does not appear.
By scrolling, I include the scroll so the keyboard does not hide the textfield.

If I change the Detail view navigationBarTitle to .inline the issues is a nearly
imperceptible flash with no permanent residual. Obviously, I will leave it in this mode
but I'd certainly prefer a standard iOS look and feel.

I've experimentally disabled every combination that I can think of - no joy.

[image]

The root List:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(myPhysicians, id: \.self) { mp in
            NavigationLink(destination: PhysicianDetailView(physician: mp)) {
                Text(mp.lastName ?? "no last name")
            }
        }
        .onDelete { indexSet in
            //standard core data delete process
        }
    }.navigationBarTitle("Physicians")
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading:
            NavigationLink(destination: AddPhysicianView()) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .font(.title)
            },
            trailing:
            EditButton()
    )//bar button items
}//nav
```

The Detail View:

```
var body: some View {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.localFirstName = self.physician.wrappedFirstName
        self.localLastName = self.physician.wrappedLastName
        //bunch more...
    }
    
    return ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
        List {
            VStack { //group 1
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("First Name:")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    if !showEditView {
                        Text("\(physician.wrappedFirstName)")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .font(.headline)
                    } else {
                        TextField("tf firstname", text: $localFirstName)
                            .modifier(TextFieldSetup())
                    }
                }
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Last Name:")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    if !showEditView {
                        Text("\(physician.wrappedLastName)")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .font(.headline)
                    } else {
                        TextField("tf lastname", text: $localLastName)
                            .modifier(TextFieldSetup())
                    }
                }
                //bunch more...
            }//outer vstack

        }//list
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity - 20)
            //.navigationBarTitle("Detail",displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
            
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {

                    if self.showEditView {
                        Text("Cancel")
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.left.circle.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                },
                trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    if self.showEditView {
                        self.saveEditedPhysicianToCoreData(physician: self.physician)
                    }
                    self.showEditView.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: self.showEditView ? "gear" : "square.and.pencil")
                        .font(.title)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                }
            )//nav bar items
    }//zstack
    .modifier(AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard())
    
}//body
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 11.6 iOS 13.6

Added: 29 July 2020

```
struct AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard: ViewModifier {

    @State var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, self.currentHeight)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(self.currentHeight == 0 ? Edge.Set() : .bottom)
            .onAppear(perform: subscribeToKeyboardEvents)
    }

    private let keyboardWillOpen = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
        .map { $0.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect }
        .map { $0.height }

    private let keyboardWillHide =  NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
        .map { _ in CGFloat.zero }

    private func subscribeToKeyboardEvents() {
        _ = Publishers.Merge(keyboardWillOpen, keyboardWillHide)
            .subscribe(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.self.currentHeight, on: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the problem is in `AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard`, would you shot its code?

Comment: I did so above. I'm pretty sure I tested with that disabled, but I will do so again.

Comment: Disabling AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard does not eliminate the issue. Do you think that .modifier could actually be changed to fix the issue?

Comment: At the same time, I needed to move navigation to this and other screens away from a 
TabBar into a Utility screen - it seems you can't have more than 5 tabs in SwiftUI - 
the extra tabs under "More..." are blank. In researching and confirming that bug I saw a 
lot of articles talking about trouble with large titles in any views that use scrolling. 
These comments go back many years.